# Keep track of score

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a quiz that shows the user the name of the state and they have to correctly state the capital. Everything works fine, except for keeping track of the user's score. I have tried to change around the score portion of the code, but nothing is working! I think the problem is somewhere in the nextCapital() function, but then again I could be wrong. I am new to python and all of this is a little overwhelming. I would really appreciate the help!

```
import tkinter
import random


capitals={"Washington":"Olympia","Oregon":"Salem",\
                "California":"Sacramento","Ohio":"Columbus",\
                "Nebraska":"Lincoln","Colorado":"Denver",\
                "Michigan":"Lansing","Massachusetts":"Boston",\
                "Florida":"Tallahassee","Texas":"Austin",\
                "Oklahoma":"Oklahoma City","Hawaii":"Honolulu",\
                "Alaska":"Juneau","Utah":"Salt Lake City",\
                "New Mexico":"Santa Fe","North Dakota":"Bismarck",\
                "South Dakota":"Pierre","West Virginia":"Charleston",\
                "Virginia":"Richmond","New Jersey":"Trenton",\
                "Minnesota":"Saint Paul","Illinois":"Springfield",\
                "Indiana":"Indianapolis","Kentucky":"Frankfort",\
                "Tennessee":"Nashville","Georgia":"Atlanta",\
                "Alabama":"Montgomery","Mississippi":"Jackson",\
                "North Carolina":"Raleigh","South Carolina":"Columbia",\
                "Maine":"Augusta","Vermont":"Montpelier",\
                "New Hampshire":"Concord","Connecticut":"Hartford",\
                "Rhode Island":"Providence","Wyoming":"Cheyenne",\
                "Montana":"Helena","Kansas":"Topeka",\
                "Iowa":"Des Moines","Pennsylvania":"Harrisburg",\
                "Maryland":"Annapolis","Missouri":"Jefferson City",\
                "Arizona":"Phoenix","Nevada":"Carson City",\
                "New York":"Albany","Wisconsin":"Madison",\
                "Delaware":"Dover","Idaho":"Boise",\
                "Arkansas":"Little Rock","Louisiana":"Baton Rouge"}


score=0
timeleft=30

print("This program will launch a capital quiz game.")
input1 = input("What difficulty would you like to play: easy, normal, or hard?\n")
if input1.lower() == "easy":
    seconds = 90
    timeleft = seconds
elif input1.lower() == "normal":
    seconds = 60
    timeleft = seconds
elif input1.lower() == "hard":
    seconds = 30
    timeleft = seconds

def startGame(event):

    #if there's still time left...
    if timeleft == seconds:
        #start the countdown timer.
        countdown()
    #run the function to choose the next colour.
    nextCapital()
    if timeleft == 0:

        endlabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="The time is up!\nYour score is: " + str(score) +" out of 50", font=('Helvetica', 12))
        endlabel.pack()
        e.pack_forget()
#function to choose and display the next colour.
def nextCapital():

    #use the globally declared 'score' and 'play' variables above.
    global score
    global timeleft

    #if a game is currently in play...
    if timeleft > 0:

        #...make the text entry box active.
        e.focus_set()


        randchoice = random.choice(list(capitals.keys()))
        answer = capitals.get(randchoice)
        if answer.lower() == randchoice.lower():
            score = score+1

####        #this deletes the random choice from the dictionary    
####        del capitals[randchoice]

        #clear the text entry box.
        e.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        #this updates the random choice label 
        label.config(text=str(randchoice))
    #update the score.
    scoreLabel.config(text="Score: " + str(score))

#a countdown timer function. 
def countdown():

    #use the globally declared 'play' variable above.
    global timeleft

    #if a game is in play...
    if timeleft > 0:

        #decrement the timer.
        timeleft -= 1
        #update the time left label.
        timeLabel.config(text="Time left: " + str(timeleft))
        #run the function again after 1 second.
        timeLabel.after(1000, countdown)

#create a GUI window.
root = tkinter.Tk()
#set the title.
root.title("Capital Quiz")
#set the size.
root.geometry("500x250")

#add an instructions label.
instructions = tkinter.Label(root, text="Brush up your geography skills!", font=('Helvetica', 12))
instructions.pack()

#add a score label.
scoreLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="Press enter to start" + str(score), font=('Helvetica', 12))
scoreLabel.pack()

#add a time left label.
timeLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="Time left: " + str(timeleft), font=('Helvetica', 12))
timeLabel.pack()

#prompt label
promptLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text= "Enter the capital of: ", font=('Helvetica', 12))
promptLabel.pack()

#add a label that will hold print the prompt
label = tkinter.Label(root, font=('Helvetica', 60))
label.pack()

#add a text entry box for typing in colours.
e = tkinter.Entry(root)
#run the 'startGame' function when the enter key is pressed.
root.bind('<Return>', startGame)
e.pack()
#set focus on the entry box.
e.focus_set()

#start the GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). "nothing is working" is not a good issue description.

Comment: You've got implicit line joining inside a dict. No need for all those backslashes in `capitals`. That just makes your code harder to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

`randchoice` is one of the *keys* in the `capitals` dict, i.e. a State.

`answer` is one of the *values* in the `capitals` dict, i.e. a Capital

You then compare the lowercase versions of `randchoice` and `answer` and increment the score if they are equal. But clearly they will never be equal (one is a State, one is a Capital). So your score won't be updated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a bit of advice: eschew all global variables, wrap things into an object with clearly defined, short methods. You will have *much* easier time working with and reasoning about the code.

Consider this skeleton of a class:

```
class Quiz(object):

  def __init__(self, difficulty, capitals_dict):
    self.score = 0
    self.capitals = capitals
    self.difficulty = ...
    self.right_answer = None

  def getNextQuestion(self):
    # Choose a capital and assign it as the current right answer
    ...
    self.right_answer = ...
    return self.right_answer # to show it to user

  def checkAnswer(user_answer):
    if user_answer == self.right_answer:
      self.score = ...
      return True
    else:
      ...

  def isGameOver(self):
    return len(self.capitals) == 0
```

I guess it's clear enough how to use a class like this, and reasonably clear how to implement it.